# D3.js transition with canvas is not smooth when mapping

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg, cartography

I'm trying to transition between two states of a d3.js map drawn on canvas and running into a little trouble: The transitions just aren't all that smooth. It's nothing like the transitions I've had with svg.

I am using the pattern described [by Irene Ros in this Bocoup blog post](https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas).

Here is my code, where I use d3.timer and a custom element to create a data abstraction from which to draw on the canvas. How can I improve the performance so each transition delay animates smoothly rather than in jerky motions?

The issue is this line: `path(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties.geometries[i]));`

Canvas takes way too long to redraw all 2144 county paths in each d3.timer() interval. So each interval is taking about 1 second, whereas to make a smooth transition it needs to take 17 ms.

Thoughts?

```
var width = 1600;

  d3.json("/data/counties_merged.json", function(error, data) {

    var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();

    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var tracts = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties);

    projection.scale(1).translate([0, 0]);

    var b = path.bounds(tracts);

    var whRatio = ((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / (b[1][1] - b[0][1]));

    var height = (width / 2) * whRatio;

    var s = .98 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
      t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];

    projection.scale(s).translate(t);

    var canvas = d3.select("#quintiles")
            .append("canvas")
              .attr("class", 'canvasarea');

    var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

    var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

    d3.select('.canvasarea')
                  .attr("width", width ).attr("height", height )
                  .style("width", ((width / ratio) ) + "px").style("height", ((height / ratio) ) + "px");


    //context.scale(ratio, ratio);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection)
        .context(context);

    if (error) throw error;


    var strokeWidth = 0.4;

    function drawCanvas(d,i) {

        // clear canvas
      context.fillStyle = "#fff";
      context.rect(0,0,canvas.attr("width"),canvas.attr("height"));
      context.fill();

      // select our dummy nodes and draw the data to canvas.
      var elements = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.county-path");
      elements.each(function(d,i) {

        context.beginPath();

          context.strokeStyle = '#333';
          context.fillStyle = d3.select(this).attr("fill");

          context.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
          path(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties.geometries[i]));

          context.stroke();
          context.fill(); 
        context.restore();

      })

    }

    // Create an in memory only element of type 'custom'
    var detachedContainer = document.createElement("custom");

    // Create a d3 selection for the detached container. We won't
    // actually be attaching it to the DOM.
    var dataContainer = d3.select(detachedContainer);

    var paths;

    function drawMap(cutoff) {

      paths = dataContainer.selectAll("custom.county-path")
        .data(data.objects.counties.geometries, function(d,i) { return d.id; });

        paths.transition().duration(0).duration(5).delay(function(d,i) { return i * 0.25; })
              .attr('fill',function(d,i) {
                return (d.quintile !== undefined) ? (d.quintile < cutoff) ? '#8A85FF' : '#efefef' : '#efefef';
              });

      paths
        .enter()
          .append('custom')
            .attr('class','county-path')
              .attr('fill',function(d,i) {
                return (d.quintile !== undefined) ? (d.quintile < cutoff) ? '#8A85FF' : '#efefef' : '#efefef';
              });
    }

    d3.timer(drawCanvas);

    drawMap(100);
    drawMap(30);

  });
```

Comment: It's hard to help without some kind of functioning testable code & data, but I see you are calling your `drawMap` function twice. Is there a reason for this? I would suspect that it is creating transitions that are fighting against each other.

Comment: The argument updates the map, using the enter update exit pattern.

Comment: An optimization strategy I've employed is to use layers of canvas on top of one another, such that the bottom layers contain images that don't change very often, and the top layer contains the changed parts.  I can't tell enough about your situation based on this code snippet.  Would you consider putting your code into a bl.ock?